# How does "ROS" Remote Control Python script over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, ros, rospy

I have a python file that driving a vehicle on gazebo simulator. From PC run testing python file sending commands to vehicle and move on without problem. When I tried to send same command 
(python drive.py ) over SSH ros packages rises below error. That is my problem .

```
kc@kc-GE60-2PC:~$ ssh remoteMachine@192.0.0.1 python moveVehicle.py
remoteMachine@'s password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 15, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    import roslib.stacks
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in <module>
    import roslib.packages
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in <module>

  from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find

  ImportError: No module named catkin.find_in_workspaces
```

I have also tried run with .sh script. But nothing has changed in error.

```
kc@kc-GE60-2PC:~$ ssh remoteMachine@192.0.0.1 ./testDrive.sh

*****SAME ERROR WİTH ABOVE CASE*****
```

I also tried : (Normally execute without SSH and Code is working fine)

```
remoteMachine@remoteMachine:~$ ./testDrive.sh 
Success Result Vehicle Moving:)
..


remoteMachine@remoteMachine:~$ python moveVehicle.py 
Success Result Vehicle Moving:)
..
```

**Error Approximation**

Error looks like ROS and $PythonPATH environment conflict problem. So if I had this error the code would never work.I am getting error with only SSH normally code and packages works fine. So what is the problem you are thinking about issue?

**That is my question:**

How can I execute my scripts over SSH without stuck any ROS environment problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as module missing. Try check that module catkin is installed.

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/user_guide/installation.html

It should be installed as is, but may be it is missing.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake python-catkin-pkg python-empy python-nose libgtest-dev
sudo pip install -U catkin_pkg
```

If it is installed, try run it from terminal. Run python and execute:

```
import catkin.find_in_workspaces
```

If module exists, add path to it in sys.path in start of your script.

Comment: Yes module exists and import success.

Comment: You mean below?`sys.path.append("/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages::/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.*")` I have edit but still error in code.

Comment: Assume, there should be something as: sys.path.extend("/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", /opt/ros/kinetic/setup/"), and may be other. sys.path is not support bash syntax, as far as I know.

Comment: here writen https://answers.ros.org/question/210800/roscore-over-ssh/, that after ssh ros environment should be enabled, by executing someting as . setup.bash, may be it help.

Comment: I tried it but not working. Also figured out something. SSH host echo $PATH' and LOCAL $PATH giving different output below:

Comment: local:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/kc/bin:/home/kc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: remote:~$ssh user@192.0.0.1 echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: ssh user@192.0.0.1 echo $PATH, should print PATH not from 192.0.0.1 because $PATH interpolation doing before, for $PATH of remote use ssh user@192.0.0.1 'echo $PATH'.  Is user for  ssh connect equal to the user that run script, when you use remote machine directly.

Comment: Newly notify me your message  "answers.ros.org/question/210800/roscore-over-ssh" I will examine

Comment: If nothing help, you can try remoteMachine@remoteMachine:~$ env, write it result to envini.sh, and run something as: ssh removeMachine@192.0.0.1 '. envini.sh; python moveVechicle.py'

Comment: I tried before this usage but nothing changed , I will try again. I think I have a environmental problem so many virtualenv exist for python in "remoteMachine". But I understand better 'what is the problem' with your help. I will focus equalize ROS package environment and SSH running environment.